# Sending email with php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am sending an email from php, but nothing is being sent, this worked at one time, and now just stopped working out of the blue:

```
function email_last_scan() {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query('UPDATE hap_stats SET emailed_reports = emailed_reports + 1');

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $filtered_data = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $_SESSION['ob_data']);

    if (isset($_SESSION['ob_data']) and $user = get_userdata($user->id))
        wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Scan Results', $filtered_data, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `if` is resolving true? you have $user = ... instead of $user ==... is that on purpose?

Comment: Stevish, good point, i'm a noob, so what your saying that the = is setting the variable rather than comparing the results, hence it's never true?

Comment: Or always true... depends on what get_userdata() is returning. But that could be done that way on purpose. In order to test, I would put an email function OUTSIDE of that `if` statement and see if that gets sent. Then you'll know that it's just that the `if` conditions are never both returning `true`

Comment: You may need to look outside the function to what you have it hooked to. Is the function even being called still? Is there another plugin interfering?

Comment: I will test outside of IF, to see if there is an issue there.  It's all sequential code on one page, but I will check to see if it's even being called. I'm assuming it is, as it was working once upon a time...thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Check once whether $_SESSION['ob_data'] and $user = get_userdata($user->id) give value or not

Comment: The value always gives FALSE hence it's not sending the email.